# Написание программ для Linux

Tags: c++, linux, windows

Подскажите, что лучше? Писать программы для линукс в самом линукс? Но тогда какую выбрать среду? Или писать в винде, но тогда какие есть особенности для линукс? Подскажите, пожалуйста. Я работаю на С++.

Comment: Linux лучше подходит для программирования на чем угодно, кроме C#, ASP и прочих заточенных под M$ технологий.

Comment: Насчет C# я бы так не утверждал. Можно замечательно на нем кодить и дебажить в MonoDevelop. И проекты, написанные в MSVS C# прекрасно собираются в Mono. Исключения будут теже, что и для любого другого языка - это использование библиотек, заточенных под конкретную платформу и GUI.

Comment: @enzo: Вы так с пренебрежением говорите о C#, будто это не лучший из мейнстримных языков.

Comment: @VladD Я не высказывал пренебрежения к шарпу, а только констатировал, что технологии MS лучше использовать в среде MS. Определение "лучший" не существует безотносительно контекста личного опыта, поставленной задачи и еще много чего. C# - [не самый популярный](http://www.tiobe.com/index.php/content/paperinfo/tpci/index.html) язык программирования, что как-бы намекает.

Comment: @enzo: Не самый популярный по версии поисковиков (а именно на них основан индекс TIOBE) — не значит не самый хороший. По скорости развития  он обходит и Java, и C, и спорит с C++. Качество C# косвенно подтверждается тем, как его фичи перенимаются другими языками (LINQ пришло в Java, async/await в Javascript, Python, Perl и другие).

Answer (score 7):

Пишите в самом линуксе. IDE взять QT Creator - кросплатформенный с множеством готовых библиотек и отличной документацией. В нем можно создать cmake проект если не устраивают проектные файлы creator'а

Answer (score 3):

При разработке на Windows у вас могут возникнуть специфичные проблемы, характерные для этой ОС. Поэтому если целевая платформа вашего приложения - Linux, то и работайте в ней. Это позволит избежать излишних проблем при портировании с Windows на Linux (особенно если это достаточно большой проект).

Небольшие примеры возможных проблем:

- Различные кодировки при выводе данных в консоль и файл (например, при логировании): если в Ubuntu по умолчанию используется Unicode, то на Windows с этим придется повозиться.
- MinGW обеспечивает минимальную эмуляцию POSIX систем, поэтому, например, при работе с сигналами можно наткнуться на [неприятную неожиданность](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34130748/signal-handling-per-process-on-windows).
- При использовании QT может понадобится дополнительная темизация отдельных элементов (сталкивался с этим на Windows - пришлось прописывать дополнительные стили для корректного отображения).
- Подключение и сборка сторонних библиотек, на мой взгляд, намного
  удобнее в Linux (упрощенно: скачал, `make`, `make install`). На
  Windows бывает приходится в ручную настраивать процесс сборки, что
  замедляет процесс разработки. Как пример, сталкивался с этим при
  подключении `libxml2`, `libxslt` и `ffmpeg`.

Для сборки проекта лучше использовать такие кросс-платформенные средства как [CMake](https://cmake.org/), это позволит избежать привязки к специфичной для ОС утилите сборки. `CMake` автоматически сгенерирует файлы управления сборкой из файлов `CMakeLists.txt`.

По поводу среды разработки: тут уже на свое усмотрение. Какая среда нравится и удобна - ту и используйте. Я в своей работе использую CLion (платная IDE, но есть небольшой хак: дистрибутив по [early access program](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/CLION/Early+Access+Program) бесплатен, учитывая их частый выход, можно использовать IDE практически свободно).

Comment: Мне казалось, что здесь идет обсуждение программирования на языке C++, а не проблемы кодировок в консолях Windows и Ubuntu. Или проблемы чьего-то взгляда на удобство сборки сторонних библиотек. И при чем здесь MinGW? На MS VS без проблем пишите код на C++, компилируйте этот код и исправляйте баги. А уже правильно написанный код без особых проблем соберёте и под Линукс (но уже в самом конце, когда все сделано... просто скомпилируете). А уже что будет написано на С++ (достаточно большой проект или может вопрошающему достаточно небольших академических задачек) здесь ни вопроса ни ответа нет.

Comment: К чему сей комментарий? Вопрос: "Подскажите, что лучше? Писать программы для линукс в самом линукс? Или писать в винде, но тогда какие есть особенности для линукс?" Где вы видите обсуждение программирования на C++?

Comment: Вырвали фразу из контекста, так в чем тогда у Вас вопросы :)

Comment: За исключением вопроса про редактор - я привел полную цитату. Автор спросил об особенностях разработки приложения под Linux на Windows -  я привел из своего опыта возможные проблемы и советы. Если вы понимаете вопрос по-другому, то это не моя проблема.

Comment: В вопросе про редактор и не пахнет, а вот язык программирования упоминается.

Answer (score 1):

Я рекомендую вам разрабатывать с использованием `Clion` от JetBrains, это кроссплатформенная IDE, где в качестве Solution выступает CMake файл, который в свою очередь позволяет сформировать солюшен для любой IDE. Если вы раньше работали с продуктами от JetBrains, то у вас не возникнет проблем с ознокомлением с этой средой.

Comment: Отмечу, что тоже самое можно сказать про IDE `Qt Creator`, она является кросплатформенной и отлично работает с Cmake файлами. Она в том числе бесплатная, в отличии от IDE `Clion`.

Comment: @AlexceiShmakov вы забили упомянуть, что Qt Creator бесплатный только для опенсорц проектов.

Comment: на приложении разве метка стоит какой версией IDE оно собрано ? ) Может продукт был опенсорс всегда, а перед выходом когда решили сделать его коммерческим собрали триальной версией платного креатора.

Comment: @Mira на сколько я помню, в опенсорц версии QTс, не все присутствует, что есть в платной версии, это раз. Во вторых, если вы пилите для гос. сектора, вы должны предоставить лицензию на продукты, которые использовали для разработки. В третьих, существует такая штука, называется проверка. А между тем Clion 20$ в месяц, в то время как QTс - 350$.

Comment: @МстиславПавлов Если вы разрабатываете в `Qt Qreator`, то это вовсе не значит, что вы используете сам фреймворк `Qt`. Можно разрабатывать без него, писать на "голом" С++, используя `Qt Creator` как среду для разработки. Тогда я как понимаю, лицензия не нужна, потому что проект можно собрать с помощью `cmake` и `make`. Поправьте, если я не прав.

Comment: @AlexceiShmakov лицензия нужна, если у вас в офисе просто стоит QtC. Более того, у вас почти наверняка будут серьезные проблемы, даже если у вас будет стоять опенсорсная версия, по тому, что вам еще нужно будет доказать, что вы не нарушали лицензию.

Comment: Согласен с  Alexcei Shmakov. Пишите на С++ на чем душе угодно и под чем угодно. У вас будут текстовые файлы .cpp, .h (и т.п.). А потом... хотите собирайте их в консоли или в IDE, хотите под Win или Linux, хотите в NetBeans или MSVC. Это уже дело вкуса. А на вкус и цвет все фломастеры разные.

Comment: @Мстислав Павлов у нас в офис без пропуска не пройдешь - потому ни каких шансов увидеть на чем нет. И опять же, еще доказать надо что данную смаке прогу компилили именно этим комьюнити креатором, а для этого надо буквально поймать за руку в момент компиляции. В общем фантастика какая то . Просто стоящая опесорсная версия не значит что ты ей компилил свой проект! У нас презумпция невиновности и доказывать должен обвинитель. А по поводу урезанности - сколько пишу - до границ библиотек еще не доходило. А там где доходило начиналось уже апи.

Answer (score 0):

Вовсе не обязательно писать программы для линукса в самом линуксе. Если для вас привычнее Windows, то под ней и пишите код. При этом пишите в той IDE, к которой привыкли, но с одним небольшим условием:

НЕ ИСПОЛЬЗУЙТЕ БИБЛИОТЕК, ТИПОВ И ФУНКЦИЙ ПРИВЯЗАННЫХ К ОПРЕДЕЛЕННОЙ ПЛАТФОРМЕ!

P.S.:Конечно же код, скомпилированный под Win, не пойдет под Линуксом. Но скомпилировать под Линуксом уже можно и готовый написанный проект. Если там и потребуются правки, то очень небольшие.

Comment: Тут все же стоит добавить, что правила сборки нужно писать на чем нибудь, из чего генерятся "проекты" под конкретные платформы. Например CMake.

Comment: Правила сборки может и разные. Но вопрос в другом, вопрос в самом написании программ под линукс. Это можно безболезненно сделать и под Win. И под линуксом только скомпилировать. И для этого вовсе не обязательны какие-то особенные IDE или порты типа MinGW, Cygwin.